# Target mailto: links with Rails::Html::TargetScrubber

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-6

I'm trying to scrub out mailto links while allowing others using [Rails::HTML](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/rails-html-sanitizer/1.0.2/Rails/Html) Scrubbers.

See: https://github.com/rails/rails-html-sanitizer

I have a [Loofah](https://github.com/flavorjones/loofah) fragment like this:

```rb
Loofah.fragment('<a href="mailto:e@example.test">tis but a scratch</a>')
```

And my Scrubber is like so:

```rb
class TargetedHtmlScrubber < Rails::Html::TargetScrubber
  def initialize
    super
    self.tags = %w[a]
  end

  def allowed_node?(node)
    ...
  end

  def scrub_attribute?(name)
    ...
  end
end
```

But when I run `scrub!` in my specs, I can't see any of the methods `allowed_node?` or `scrub_attribute` being called as per the [documentation](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/rails-html-sanitizer/1.0.2/Rails/Html/TargetScrubber).

My spec is like this. It scrubs everything..,.

```rb
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe TargetedHtmlScrubber do
  describe 'targeting html tags' do
    it 'ignores <a>' do
      fragment = html_fragment('<a href="http://example.test">Greg! the stop sign!!</a>')
      expect(
        fragment.scrub!(subject).to_s
      ).to eq '<a href="http://example.test">Greg! the stop sign!!</a>'
    end

    it 'targets <a href=mailto:>' do
      fragment = html_fragment('<a href="mailto:e@example.test">tis but a scratch</a>')
      expect(
        fragment.scrub!(subject).to_s
      ).to eq 'tis but a scratch'
    end
  end
end
```

I am expecting to implement something in one of the two methods in my class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I worked it out. To call those methods, you need to set the tags and attributes arrays:

```
  def initialize
    super
    self.tags = %w[a]
    self.attributes = %w[href]
  end
```

It will then call `allowed_node?(node)` and `scrub_attribute?(name)`. So in this case, I only need the tags.

To scrub out `mailto:` links:

```rb
class TargetedHtmlScrubber < Rails::Html::TargetScrubber
  def initialize
    super
    self.tags = %w[a]
  end

  def allowed_node?(node)
    href(node) !~ /^mailto:/
  end

  private

  def href(node)
    node.try(:attributes)['href'].try(:value)
  end
end
```